# Select the value in a dynamic select box based on the object value

Tags: jquery, html, object, dynamic, dropdown

I've an array ob object using which I'm creating dynamic divs.
Each of my object has a property 'logoColor' which has a value either 1 or 2.

Now in each of my dynamic div I've a dropdown 'Logo Colour' which has a value of 1 or 2. But, it is displayed as 'Red' or 'Blue'.

How do I make sure the selected value in my dynamic dropdown is based on the corresponding object value?

For e.g., for the object with company as 'BCD', I should see '2' or 'Blue' as selected.

Here's my code

```js
var myData = [{
  "company": "ABC",
  "logoColor": "1"
}, {
  "company": "BCD",
  "logoColor": "2"
}, {
  "company": "CDE",
  "logoColor": "1"
}, {
  "company": "DEF",
  "logoColor": "2"
}];

function createDisplay() {
  myData.forEach(function(obj) {
    $('.container').append(
      $('<div>').addClass('box').append(
        $('<label>').text('Company Website: '),
        $('<a>').addClass('compUrl').attr('href', obj.url).text(obj.company),
        $('<br /><label>').text('Logo Colour: '),
        $('<select>').addClass('form-control').append(
          $('<option>').val('1').text('Red').prop('selected', true),
          $('<option>').val('2').text('Blue')
        )
      )
    )
  });
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="createDisplay()">Create Data </button>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way given your current code, would be to just add `.val(obj.logoColor)` after your `append()` call like this:

```js
var myData =[{
    "company": "ABC",
    "logoColor": "1"
     },{
    "company" : "BCD",
    "logoColor": "2"
     },{
    "company" : "CDE", 
    "logoColor": "1"
     },{
     "company" : "DEF", 
     "logoColor": "2"
   }];
   
function createDisplay() {
 myData.forEach(function(obj) {
  $('.container').append(
   $('<div>').addClass('box').append(
    $('<label>').text('Company Website: '),
    $('<a>').addClass('compUrl').attr('href', obj.url).text(obj.company),
    $('<br /><label>').text('Logo Colour: '),
    $('<select>').addClass('form-control').append(
     $('<option>').val('1').text('Red').prop('selected', true),
     $('<option>').val('2').text('Blue')
    ).val(obj.logoColor)
   )
  )
 });
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="createDisplay()">Create Data </button> 
<div class="container">
 
</div>
```